# Как заполнить двумерный вектор c++

Tags: vector, c++

```
vector<vector<int>> a;
```

Допустим, есть цикл:

```
for (int i =0;i<n;i++)
cin >> x >> y; 
//a[i][0]=x;
//a[i][1]=y;
//a.push_back()?
```

А как с вектором?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала строки со столбцами создать. А потом можно работать аналогично сырым(*raw, то есть обычным*) массивам через `vec[i][j]` :

```
vector<vector<int>> vec;
// 3x5
vec.reserve(3);
for (int i = 0, size = vec.size(); i < size; ++i)
    vec[i].reserve(5);
```

Comment: а нельзя проще для вектора где всего 2 столбца?
Например для x,y или что нибуть подобное

Comment: vec.reserve(2);
    vec[0].reserve(j);
    vec[1].reserve(j);

Comment: Огромное Спасибо!